# Convert JSON object to response object and back to JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, fetch, blob, javascript-objects

I'm writing unit tests where I use the fetch command to return a response object back and store it in a variable.

But when I try to convert back to text, it returns `[object Blob]`

Any ideas of what's going wrong?

Here's my code:

```
const obj = { hello: "world" };
const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2)], {
  type: "application/json",
});
var init = { "status" : 200 , "statusText" : "SuperSmashingGreat!" };
var myResponse = new Response(blob, init);
console.log(await myResponse.text()); // [object Blob]
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong? I want to get "hello world" back from the response.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](https://www.benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: No, it doesn't; it outputs `{"hello": "world"}` https://jsfiddle.net/ybL1td5m/

Comment: @kikon I think the OP is saying they want to get it back as an Object instead of a string. I've posted my answer below.

Comment: @ParkingMaster right, that's great. I'm just saying there are no surprises here, `.text()` is text and one may even parse it

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `.text()`, **use** `.json()`:

```js
const obj = { hello: "world" };
const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2)], {
  type: "application/json",
});
var init = { "status" : 200 , "statusText" : "SuperSmashingGreat!" };
var myResponse = new Response(blob, init);
console.log(await myResponse.json()); // { ... }
```

The reason it's returning `[object Blob]` is because `.text()` gets the value of the parameter (in your case `myResponse`), and it returns the value as `toString()`:

```js
object = new Blob();

console.log(object.toString());

console.log(object);
```

*Additionally*, if you want it to return **the blob** as a string, use `JSON.stringify`:

```js
let blob = new Blob();

console.log(JSON.stringify(blob));

console.log(blob.toString());

console.log(blob);
```

Comment: Really weird. This works as expected on JSFiddle but on my local environment it does not. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

So what ended up working was install `whatwg-fetch` package and importing the response object from there rather than using NodeJS's.

```js
import { Response } from 'whatwg-fetch';
```